# How to submit an archived app to App Store manually

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, submit, xcode3.2

XCode 3.2.5 is giving me grief. Nothing is wrong either in the app in App Store or in the App. "Validate..." succeeds, "Submit..." has no complaints. But after 10 seconds or so I get "*an error occurred uploading to the itunes store*".

I've uploaded two apps previously, this is the first one since XCode 3.2.5.

I've downloaded the .dmg of **Application Loader** 1.3 from the similar thread, but without a link to Apple saying this is the solution, I won't downgrade.

The alternative, I guess, is to somehow just get the file up there. Is it allowed / possible and how do I do it if so?

Edit: At first I thought App Loader was a component of XCode, but apparently it's a standalone application. So it should be downgradable if you have problems with getting the answer to work, but 1.4 worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for adding the tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the archive and "Reveal in Finder". You will find a .app bundle inside it. Compress it and upload the Zip using Application Loader.

Oflate, the XCode's built in app submission is showing some strange errors.

Comment: Easier than anticipated with this accurate description! Adding this step to the guide I've typed. Since there's usually a month or two between submissions it's all too easy to miss a step :)

Comment: (Actually at first I thought App Loader was what XCode used to submit and thought downgrading to 1.3 would change part of XCode... hence the confused statement in my question, will edit that now.)